# FFMPEG overlay two video and add text

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to overlay two videos and add time on the video.

When I merge two videos with

```
ffmpeg \
-y \
-i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 \
-filter_complex " \
    [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=720x720[top]; \
    [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=240x240[bottom]; \
    [top][bottom]overlay=x=10:y=10:eof_action=pass" \
-acodec aac -vcodec libx264 merge.mp4
```

And it works.

But when I try to add text on it with

```
ffmpeg \
-y \
-i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 \
-filter_complex " \
    [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=720x720[top]; \
    [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=240x240[bottom]; \
    [top][bottom]overlay=x=10:y=10:eof_action=pass; \
    drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf:text=yo" \
-acodec aac -vcodec libx264 merge.mp4
```

I got error

> Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_drawtext_5

How should I modify my command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters which operate upon the output of another filter in a chain, should be separated by a comma. So,

```
[top][bottom]overlay=x=10:y=10:eof_action=pass, \
    drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf:text=yo"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
May I ask another question, if I want to change the text to time and start with the time I insert?

Comment: Like this, `drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf:text=yo:enable='between(t,10,15)'`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.
I mean change the text to the time, like the video is 10 sec. And start at 00:12:10
so the text start from 00:12:10 and change every second finally end with 00:12:20

Comment: You'll need the pts variable, see https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Text-expansion