# Add a Text and a images to the video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have read  this question in toppic:
[FFMPEG overlay two video and add text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781146/ffmpeg-overlay-two-video-and-add-text)

```
ffmpeg -i raw_video.mp4 -i watermark.png -i watermark2.png -filter_complex [0:v]drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='text1':fontcolor=black@1.0:fontsize=24:x=20:y=259, drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='text2':fontcolor=black@1.0:fontsize=24:x=500:y=500[text]; [text][1:v]overlay=215:0[ol1];[ol1][2:v]overlay=400:300[filtered]"-map "[filtered]" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy output.mp4  "
```

I try to using this ffmpeg but it error .

Please help me

Comment: You need to provide the error. Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: Hi llogan, I try add a image and a text with command below, but I see a image on video and the text don't display  : ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i images.png -filter_complex "[0:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)';[v]drawtext=text='abccccc':fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf:x=(w-text_w):y=(h-text_h):fontsize=30:fontcolor=white" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output123.mp4

Answer (score -1):

## Your first command

#### Problem 1: The command has a trailing `"` resulting in an error:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55f096873c40] No such filter: ''
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Remove the trailing `"`.

#### Problem 2: Missing space

Change `[filtered]"-map` to `[filtered]" -map`.

#### Problem 3: Filtergraph not quoted

Enclose the filtergraph in quotes: `"[0:v]drawtext...overlay=400:300[filtered]"`

---

## Your second command

#### Problem: Unlabeled filterchain is ignored

Change `enable='between(t,0,20)';[v]drawtext` to `enable='between(t,0,20)',drawtext` and read [Filtering Introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) and [Filtergraph description](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description).